# how to fix TS2322: could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'unknown'

Tags: typescript, react-native, generics, typescript-generics

I'm trying to wrap up a React Native generic component and expose the same generic type to the outside. But typescript gives this error. `'unknown' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'unknown'.` I tried various approaches but couldn't be able to get around this error. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

*Dropdown.tsx*

```js
export type DropdownProps<S> = {
  itemText?: (item: S) => string;
};

const Dropdown = <S extends unknown>(props: DropdownProps<S>) => {
...
}
```

*DropdownWrapper.tsx*

```js
export type DropdownWrapperProps<T> = {
  name: string;
} & DropdownProps<T>;

const DropdownWrapper = <T extends unknown>(
  props: DropdownWrapperProps<T>,
) => {
  const {
    name,
    ...rest
  } = props;

  return (
    <>
    ...
      <Dropdown {...rest} /> <======= ERROR
    ...
    </>
  );
}
```

*complete error*

```js
Types of property 'itemText' are incompatible.
Type '((item: T) => string) | undefined' is not assignable to type '((item: unknown) => string) | undefined'.
Type '(item: T) => string' is not assignable to type '(item: unknown) => string'.
Types of parameters 'item' and 'item' are incompatible.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'unknown' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'unknown'.
```